# How to apply linear impulse to variable point

Tags: java, android, box2d, libgdx

I'm making simple Android game in LibGDX framework. I stucked at one point and I hope that you can help me. 
I wan't to apply linear impulse at a fixed point. When W is pressed program should check player angle and apply impulse to the right point.

`player.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0,1000),
new Vector2((float)Math.cos(angle)*player.getPosition().x,(float)Math.sin(angle)*player.getPosition().y/2), true);`

When I'm pressing W player is going up without any problems.

But when I press D and player angle is changed:

`player.applyTorque(2000, true);`

If I press W again player starts rotating. What can I do to apply an inpulse in a correct way to player? I want player to behave like a rocket, or "jetpack"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [Body.getWorldVector(...)](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Body.html#getWorldVector%28com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2%29) to retrieve a local vector in world coordinates. You could try this:

```
Vector2 forward = player.getWorldVector(new Vector2(0, 1)).nor();
player.applyForceToCenter(forward.x * strength, forward.y * strength);
```